# How are non-associative groups called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, definition

Is there a name for the algebraic objects that have all the properties of groups except associativity?

For example, the unit octonions have this property. They satisfy the following definition.

> **Definition:** A set $G$ is called a _________ if there is a binary operation $\cdot:G\times G\to G$ such that
>
> 1. (Identity) There exists an element $e\in G$, such that $e \cdot a = a \cdot e = a$ for all $a\in G$.
> 2. (Inverse) For all $a \in G$, there exists an element $b \in G$ such that $a \cdot b = b \cdot a = e$.

Comment: You should look up loops. I forgot if they are precisely what you have here, but they are certainly close

Comment: See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup#Loop)

Comment: In a loop, left and right inverses don't have to be the same. But also, without associativity, existence of inverses doesn't imply cancellation ($ax=bx\Rightarrow a=b$ and $xa=xb\Rightarrow a=b$), as you could just take any set $\{e,a_0,b_0,a_1,b_1,\dots\}$ with a binary operation such that $e$ is an identity and $a_i,b_i$ are inverse to each other, and then define the binary operation in a completely arbitrary way on all other pairs of elements. So you probably want cancellation rather than inverses in your definition to get something reasonable.

Comment: You are close to a Mufang loop; certainly, every Mufang has two-sided inverses and an identity, but they are usually defined via other identities, which I do not know if they are satisfied from simply assuming the existence of an identity and inverses.

Answer (score 0):

This is called an "non-associative group" or "invertible loop" according to [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nonassociative+group) or [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.5059.pdf):

> Most algebraic systems like groups, rings, and ﬁelds satisfy some or
> all of the following axioms or postulates:
>
> Axiom 1. For all $a, b ∈ S$, $a ⋆ b ∈ S$. (Closure axiom)
>
> Axiom 2. There exists a unique element $e ∈ S$, called the identity, such that $e ⋆ a = a ⋆ e = a$ for all $a ∈ S$. (Identity axiom)
>
> Axiom 3. Given an identity element $e ∈ S$, for every $a ∈ S$ there exists a unique element $a^{−1} ∈ S$, called its inverse, such
> that $a ⋆ a^{−1} = a^{−1} ⋆ a = e$. (Inverse axiom)
>
> Axiom 4. For every $a, b ∈ S$ there exists unique $x, y ∈ S$ such that $a ⋆ x = b$ and $y ⋆ a = b$.
> (Unique Solution axiom)
>
> Axiom 5. For every $a, b ∈ S, a ⋆ b = b ⋆ a$.
> (Commutative axiom)
>
> Axiom 6. For all $a, b, c ∈ S$, $(a ⋆ b) ⋆ c = a ⋆ (b ⋆ c)$. (Associative axiom)
>
> The simplest algebraic system is the groupoid ; it is only required to satisfy A1.
> This is a trivial system and not much can be said about it. A groupoid that also
> satisﬁes A4 is called a quasigroup; and a quasigroup that satisﬁes A2 is called a
> loop
>
> […]
>
> A loop that also satisﬁes A3 is called an invertible loop. Such a loop can be either associative or non-associative.

In short, if you satisfy Axiom 1 through 4, you are an invertible loop.

(I believe) this match your definition above:

- Axiom 1 is given by the co-domain and domain of your operation ⋅,
- Axiom 2 is your identity,
- I believe unit octonions have a unique inverse element (your question just asked for its existence, and I don't think its uniqueness can be derived from your definition), which gives Axiom 3,
- And for Axiom 4 I believe it can be proven that (writing $a^{-1}$ for the inverse of $a$) $a^{-1} ⋅ b$ in both cases gives you what you need, and can be proven unique.