# Can there exist a non-associative operation with an identity element,such that every element has an inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, inverse, associativity

As far as my understanding goes, the inverse of each element need not be even unique based on what is given. But it looks like they are asking for a where it is actually unique despite it needing not to be. And I am not being able to come up with an example even after trying trying. Can you guys suggest a few examples. And also, can you please share the thought process behind it, like how you came up with it?

Comment: Perhaps this could prove to be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686945/how-are-non-associative-groups-called

Comment: Google loops and quasi-groups.

Comment: @John what will be the identity in your example?

Comment: Thank you for suggesting to look up quasi group,but is it possible for someone to construct an example from scratch?

Comment: I think the easiest example is $(\mathbb Z , -)$, this is not associatve but the other criteria are met.

Comment: Thank you @Targon, this is what I was looking for. Did you come up with it now or you knew it from before?

Comment: I saw it on an exercise sheet for a class I was a teaching assistant for once. There the question was to prove or disprove whether this object is a group or not. so I didn't come up with it myself but you can'treally forget it because it's so easy and nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you don't have any constraint on the set and the operation it's not hard to create one by just adding new element to a set with a non associative operator and then extending the operator.

For instance take $S=\mathbb{R}^3$ with the vector product $\wedge$, which is a not associative operator which has no inverse.
Take a copy of $S$ and call it $\bar S$. Assume there is a bijection $S\to \bar S$ with maps a element $s$ in $\bar s$. Define a new set $S'$ as
$$S' = S\cup \bar S\cup\{E,F\}\,.$$
You can extend $\wedge$ in the following way. For $v,w\in S$ just the usual $v\wedge w$. For $\bar v,\bar w\in\bar S$ you can define $\bar v\wedge \bar w = \overline{v\wedge w}$. For $v\neq w$ define $v\wedge \bar w = \bar v \wedge w = F$. Then $v\wedge \bar v=\bar v \wedge v = E$. Finally define $F\wedge v = v\wedge F =F\wedge \bar v=\bar v\wedge F = F$. Then $F\wedge F = E\wedge E = E$. And finally make $E$ to be the unit element, i.e. for all $s\in S'$, $s\wedge E = E\wedge s = E$.

It seems very complicated but the idea is just that if you have a set with an associative operation you can add a copy of being the inverse, together with a neutral element. Then I introduced $F$ just to make it easier to extend the operation.

Comment: Thank you! This is precisely what I figured out from the other answer and commented the same.

Comment: Accepted your answer because it gives a complete process of construction of such an operation.

Answer (score 5):

[Multiplication of (nonzero) octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion#Conjugate,_norm,_and_inverse) is non-associative but has inverses.

For a simpler if less natural example, consider $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ and let $*$ be the operation given as follows:

- $\infty*a=a*\infty=a$ for all $a$.
- For $a\not=b$ in $\mathbb{R}$, we set $a*b={a+b\over 2}$.
- For each $a\in\mathbb{R}$ we set $a*a=\infty$.

In this structure $\infty$ functions as the identity element and each element is its own inverse, but $*$ is nonassociative.

Comment: This is really smart. I see how you came up with this construction. First the average, which is non associative, and defining one indentity which is outside our set at first and then including it and then defining the operation, so that every element operating on itself gives that identity. Targons example above is a more natural one though.